# IPC - How to redirect a command output to a shared memory segment in child

Tags: linux, ipc

I tried to redirect (write) a Unix command output to a shared memory segment in the child,
and then have the parent read the output back out from the same shared memory segment in the parent process. I don't have a lot of success after few futile attempts. Can anyone show me a way?
thanks in advance.

## My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#define SHM_SIZE    1024

int main()
{
   key_t key; int  shmid; char* data;

   pid_t   cpid=fork();

   if (cpid<0) 
   {
         fprintf(stderr,"Fork error!\n");
         exit (-1);
   }
   else if (cpid==0)        // child process
   {
    if ((key = ftok("mysh.c", 'R')) == -1)
        { 
            perror("ftok");
            exit(1);
        }

    // Connect to shared memory 
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
    {
       perror("shmget");
       exit(1);
    }

    // Attach to the segment
    data = shmat(shmid, (void *) 0, 0);
    if (data == (char *) (-1))
    {
       perror("shmat");
       exit(1);
    }

        system("ls -l");
    // Stuck: How to redirect the output of "ls -l"
    // to a shared memmory segment "data", so that parent process
    // can retrieve it later?? Tried to 
    // do pipe and dup2 but none worked.

    // Attempt via read?, but only garbage
    read(STDIN_FILENO, data, SHM_SIZE);

   }
   else 
   { // parent process
    int st;

    wait(&st);
    printf("Output read from the child:\n");
        if ((write(STDOUT_FILENO, data, SHM_SIZE)) < 0 )
        {
            perror("write 2");
            exit(1);
    }
   }
}
```

======================

Comment: Why do you not use a pipe for the parent to read output of child process?

Comment: The exercise that I wanted to learn/practice is the shared memory segment. I wonder if piping it to file-descriptor, and then again re-directing it from fd to a shared memory buffer, would do the job. That sounds redundant, not sure.

Comment: If you use pipe, shared memory is unnecessary. This one is easier and the normal way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to redirect stdout of the ls -l**

We must shed more light on the processes (parent and children) involved into this code.
How many processes your program creates during its run?
The correct answer is - **three**.
Two processes are the parent and the explicitly forked child.
The third one is created by the **system("ls -l")** call.
This function implicitly forks another process that executes (by calling an exec family function) the "ls -l" sell command. What you need to redirect is the output of the child process created by the **system()** function. It is sad, but the **system()** does not establish IPC between the participators. If you need to manipulate with the output, do not use system().

I agree with @leeduhem, **popen()** could be the best approach.
It works exactly as the **system()**, i.e. forks a new process and executes "ls -l".
In addition, it also establishes a pipe IPC between the participators, so it is easy to catch the child output and to do with it whatever you want:

```
char buff[1024];
FILE *fd;

// instead of system("ls -l")
fd = popen("ls -l", "r");
// check for errors

while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fd) != NULL)
{
  // write to the shared memory
}
 
pclose(fd);
```

If you do not want to use the **popen()** function, you may write a similar one.
The general approach is

1. open a **pipe()**
2. **fork()** a new process
3. redirect stdout using dup2
4. call a suitable **exec()** function (probably **execl()**) executing "ls -l"
5. read from the descriptor you are duplicating by dup2.

Answer (score 3):

```
    system("ls -l");
// Stuck: How to redirect the output of "ls -l"
// to a shared memmory segment "data", so that parent process
// can retrieve it later?? Tried to 
// do pipe and dup2 but none worked.
```

For test purpose, I suggest you read from `stdin`, then write them to `data`.

---

Here is an example using POSIX shared memory (POSIX IPC API is better than SYSV IPC API), which child read from `stdin` to a shared memory region, and parent write the content of this shared memory region to `stdout`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *shm_name = "/dummy_cat_shm";
    int shm_fd;
    off_t shm_length;

    const char *read_sem_name = "/dummy_cat_read";
    const char *write_sem_name = "/dummy_cat_write";

    sem_t *read_sem, *write_sem;
    pid_t pid;
    int buf_length;
    char *write_ptr, *read_ptr;

    buf_length = 1024;
    shm_length = sizeof(buf_length) + buf_length;

    /* Create semaphore */
    read_sem = sem_open(read_sem_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    if (read_sem == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        goto clean_up3;
    }
    write_sem = sem_open(write_sem_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
    if (write_sem == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        goto clean_up2;
    }

    /* Create shared memory segment */
    shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (shm_fd < 0) {
        perror("shm_open");
        goto clean_up1;
    }

    if (ftruncate(shm_fd, shm_length) < 0) {
        perror("ftruncate");
        goto clean_up0;
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        goto clean_up0;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        write_ptr = mmap(NULL, shm_length, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
        if (write_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("mmap");
            goto clean_up0;
        }

        char *buf = write_ptr+sizeof(buf_length);

        while (sem_wait(write_sem) == 0) {
            if (fgets(buf, buf_length, stdin) != NULL) {
                *(int *)write_ptr = 1;
                sem_post(read_sem);
            }
            else {
                *(int *)write_ptr = 0;
                sem_post(read_sem);
                break;
            }
        }

        munmap(write_ptr, shm_length);
    }
    else {
        read_ptr = mmap(NULL, shm_length, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
        if (read_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("mmap");
            goto clean_up0;
        }

        char *buf = read_ptr + sizeof(buf_length);

        while (sem_wait(read_sem) == 0) {
            if (*(int *)read_ptr > 0) {
                printf("%s", buf);
                sem_post(write_sem);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        munmap(read_ptr, shm_length);
    }

clean_up0:
    shm_unlink(shm_name);

clean_up1:
    sem_unlink(write_sem_name);

clean_up2:
    sem_unlink(read_sem_name);

clean_up3:
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Note: these two `mmap()` could be put before `fork()` in this case.

Compiling:

```
gcc shm_exp.c -pthread -lrt
```

Running:

```
$ ls / | ./a.out 
bin/   home/        lib32/       mnt/   run/      sys/  vmlinuz@
boot/  initrd.img@  lib64/       opt/   sbin/     tmp/  vmlinuz.old@
dev/   initrd.img.old@  lost+found/  proc/  selinux/  usr@
etc/   lib/     media/       root/  srv/      var/
```